# How to fix: Using an GUI to input an abbreviated month and then change that abbreviated month to its corresponding MM format

Tags: autohotkey

The below is a snippet of a much larger script that is using the main variable %Month% given by the GUI for most purposes. I need to then change that abbreviated %Month% variable into the MM date format (ex: Jul = 07) and store that data as a new variable %month%.

```
   #NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases. ; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors. SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability. SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
    
    
Gui, Add, Text,, Abbrivated Month (Case Sensitive Ex: Jul):
Gui, Add, Edit, vMonth
Gui, Add, Button, default, Submit  ; The label ButtonOK (if it exists) will be run when the button is pressed.
Gui, Show,, Date at the end of the target file
return 

GuiClose:
ButtonSubmit:
Gui, Submit

if (%Month% = Jan)
{
    month = 01
}
else
{
    if (%Month% = Feb)
    {
        month = 02
    }
    else
    {
        if (%Month% = Mar)
        {
            month = 03
        }
        else
        {
            if (%Month% = Apr)
            {
                month = 04
            }
            else
            {
                if (%Month% = May)
                {
                    month = 05
                }
                else
                {
                    if (%Month% = Jun)
                    {
                        month = 06
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (%Month% = Jul)
                        {
                            month = 07
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (%Month% = Aug)
                            {
                                month = 08
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (%Month% = Sep)
                                {
                                    month = 09
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (%Month% = Oct)
                                    {
                                        month = 10
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (%Month% = Nov)
                                        {
                                            month = 11
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            if (%Month% = Dec)
                                            {
                                                month = 12
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                MsgBox, Invalid Month
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }   
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
MsgBox, %month%

ExitApp
```

When running the script above, I am only getting the %month% = 01 whereas I would like the %month% variable to be changed to the corresponding monthly MM value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Variable names in an** [**expression**](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Variables.htm#Expressions) **are not enclosed in percent signs**.
>
> Consequently, **literal strings must be enclosed in
> double quotes** to distinguish them from variables.

```
#NoEnv
Gui, Add, Text,, Abbrivated Month (Case Sensitive Ex: Jul):
Gui, Add, Edit, vMonth
Gui, Add, Button, default, Submit  ; The label ButtonOK (if it exists) will be run when the button is pressed.
Gui, Show,, Date at the end of the target file
return 

GuiClose:
ButtonSubmit:
Gui, Submit

if (Month = "Jan")
    month = 01
else if (Month = "Feb")
    month = 02
else if (Month = "Mar")
    month = 03
else if (Month = "Apr")
    month = 04
else if (Month = "May")
    month = 05
else if (Month = "Jun")
    month = 06
else if (Month = "Jul")
    month = 07
else if (Month = "Aug")
    month = 08
else if (Month = "Sep")
    month = 09
else if (Month = "Oct")
    month = 10
else if (Month = "Nov")
    month = 11
else if (Month = "Dec")
    month = 12
else 
{
    MsgBox, Invalid Month
    ExitApp
}
MsgBox, % month
ExitApp
```